# Как подключать файлы без повторений

Tags: c++, c

Опишу на простом примере.

Есть `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "f1.h"

int main(void)
{
    f1();
    printf("123\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`f1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1()
{
    printf("fwefw\n");
}
```

`f1.h`:

```
void f1();
```

Проблема заключается в том что на этапе сборки код из `<stdio.h>` дублируется два раза, оно и понятно потому что он подключен и в `main.c` и в `f1.c` но если я убираю этот заголовок из `f1.c` то мне при компиляции выдает предупреждение `warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf'`

Как правильно организовать код что бы не было дублирования кода стандартных библиотек и не получать предупреждений от компилятора ?

Пробовал еще такой ваирант, создавал файл `general.h`:

```
#ifndef GENERAL_INC
#define GENERAL_INC

#include <stdio.h>

#endif
```

и включал этот файл в `main.c` и `f1.c`, но все равно код с `<stdio.h>` дублируется.

Как сделать все правильно ? если что компилирую так: `gcc f1.c main.c`

Comment: Что плохого в том, что stdio включается в обоих файлах?

Comment: #ifndef и #define во всех хедерах своих

Comment: @Evgenii Izhboldin я же написал что так пробовал  и привел в пример заголовочный файл `general.h` который я подключал и в `main.c` и в `f1.c` все равно код дублируется!

Comment: @Croessmah ну как минимум то что если большой проект и будет куча зависимостей в 100 файлах от кучи стандартных библиотек, то код будет скопирован 1000 раз один и тот же, я даже не знаю что там с компиляцией будет в таком случае, это вообще то не нормально что идет дублирование кода на этапе сборки компилятора

Comment: @Gar, во всех заголовочных  файлах  придерживаются правилом одного определения с помощью условной компиляции, в результате код не дублируется

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan понял спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f1.h:

```
#pragma once
void f1();
```

f1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "f1.h"  

void f1()
{
    printf("fwefw\n");
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "f1.h"
int main(void)
{
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Но вы сколько угодно раз можете подключать , он всеравно подключится один раз

Answer (score 1):

Файлы заголовков не компилируются сами по себе. Их подключат в файлы компилируемого кода (.cpp, .c, .cxx, etc.).
Как правило, они содержат только объявления типов, переменных, функций для того, чтобы следовать [правилу одного определения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
Код стандартной библиотеки не будет скопирован при подключении `stdio.h`. Возможно, некоторые функции определённые в файле заголовка будут встроены, но это решит компилятор.

Не нужно избегать подключения файлов заголовков только чтобы избежать "дублирования кода". Заголовки нужно подключать в тех файлах, которые требуют этого. К примеру, если C++ файл использует `printf`, то он должен подключить заголовок в котором эта функция объявлена (`cstdio`).

Наличие "лишних" подключённых файлов заголовков, в подавляющем большинстве случаев, никак не повлияет на размер получившегося в итоге исполняемого файла или его скорость работы. Единственное, на чём это отразится - на скорости компилирования, да и то будет заметно только лишь на очень больших проектах.

Comment: Предпроцессируются тем не менее, а так же посмотрите про LTO.

Answer (score -2):

Возможно будет полезно к ознакомлению: [Include-what-you-use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use)